# Bitbake stopped in do_fetch

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

I have been trying to create a Linux image for the VAR-SOM-MX8X. Its been a rough beginning, but I have managed to create the layers and so. I have bitbaked 2 days ago and left the system working, I already knew it was going to be a long way.

The problem is since yesterday at 23:26  the log inside of my tmp/buildstats/ shows me the build has been trying to download me this Git package,

```
git clone --branch imx_5.4.24_2.1.0  https://source.codeaurora.org/external/imx/linux-imx.git
```

I have tried to download it by myself with git clone and it starts, its huge, but it downloads properly. The problem is the bitbake download doesn't look like its working, the progress bar has stayed all day long in 41% and it doesn't look like its working.

-- UPDATE

okey, I didn't know you could actually stop bitbake by Ctr+C twice, one first and another after the "wait for executiioning tasks" dialogue appears. Anyway my download has not gone far, my system stays downloading the same git path all the time and it doesnt make any change, once it has managed to go to 100% but then it has stopped there forever. Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: Can it be RAM related issue? I am bitbaking it in a virtual machine with not much RAM, my PC only has 4GB and almost crashed when the virtual machine used 2GB, so I put 1GB only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally managed to get the image, the problem may be about connectivity issue. First, I tried to do it in my work laptop in my office but it was too slow. Finally, trying to do it in my home PC I have managed to get the image, some recipes fail, but with

```
bitbake <image_name> -c cleanall
```

I have managed to get everything done. Moreover, nodejs didnt compile properly, so I remove it out of my local.conf file and everythign worked fine.